# Firebird execute procedure and statement (with result from that procedure as part of it) inside trigger

Tags: stored-procedures, triggers, firebird, firebird2.5

I want to execute a before update trigger, which checks if all the fields in a row are the same and cancel the update. I'm using Firebird 2.5.

My current approach is this:

- Use procedure to get all names of fields with `old.FIELD`, `new.FIELD`. Something like this:

  ```
  IF (new.LOCATION IS DISTINCT FROM
  old.LOCATION) OR (new.NAME IS DISTINCT FROM old.NAME)
  ```

  ... the return type of procedure is `Varchar(1000)`. This works. The procedure is this: `STRING_SESTAVLJEN_ENAKOST_TABEL('MERILA_STRANKE');`
- If this condition is true, I want to insert some values into `SYNC_INFO` table and proceed with the update of the row. If the condition is false, I want to cancel the update row. I do that by throwing an exception.

My code:

```
SET TERM ^ ;
ALTER TRIGGER BI_MERILA_STRANKE ACTIVE
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE POSITION 0
AS 
declare variable besedilo_primerjave varchar(5000);

BEGIN 
    begin

         if (new.ID_MERILA_STRANKE is null OR new.ID_MERILA_STRANKE = 0) then new.ID_MERILA_STRANKE = gen_id(GEN_ID_MERILA_STRANKE,1);
    end

    begin    
        besedilo_primerjave = execute procedure 
STRING_SESTAVLJEN_ENAKOST_TABEL('MERILA_STRANKE');   -- if this is true then you need to save othervise not

         execute statement besedilo_primerjave || ' THEN BEGIN INSERT INTO SYNC_INFO(TABLE_NAME,ID_COLUMN_NAME,ID_VALUE,DATETIME) 
        VALUES (
            ''MERILA_STRANKE'',
            ''ID_MERILA_STRANKE'',
            NEW.ID_MERILA_STRANKE,
            CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
        );

        END ELSE BEGIN

            exception ENAK_RECORD;

        END';
    end
END^
SET TERM ; ^
```

When I try to execute this, I get the following error:

> Token unknown - line 18, column 10
>   execute

This is this line of code:

```
execute statement besedilo_primerjave || ' THEN BEGIN INSERT INTO SYNC_INFO(TABLE_NAME,ID_COLUMN_NAME,ID_VALUE,DATETIME)
```

I am not working a lot with Firebird, so if anyone has any idea what I'm doing wrong, or if anyone knows a better solution to achieve this, please help me.

I need to do it on database, probably better approach would be to do it in software, but I can not do that.

Comment: I rolled back your edit, as it changes the scope of the question. Please post a new question if you run into a new problem (even if it is the same code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are wrong about the problematic line. The actual problem is on

```
besedilo_primerjave = execute procedure STRING_SESTAVLJEN_ENAKOST_TABEL('MERILA_STRANKE');
```

You can't have `execute procedure` after assignment, you need to use

```
execute procedure STRING_SESTAVLJEN_ENAKOST_TABEL('MERILA_STRANKE')
    returning_values :besedilo_primerjave;
```

Your next statement cannot work as [`execute statement`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-psql-execstmt) cannot be used to execute snippets of PSQL (procedural SQL) like that, it can only execute normal DSQL (dynamic SQL), and you cannot access the context variables (like `new`) in that way. You would need to pass the required columns from `new` explicitly as parameter values to `execute statement`, and you could try if you can get it to work by wrapping the PSQL you try to execute dynamically in an [`execute block`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-dml-execblock), but that would turn ugly pretty fast.

I suggest you rethink what you're doing, and maybe write the real logic in a trigger, instead of trying to do it fully dynamic like you're trying to do now.

Comment: Thank you... i fixed it a bit... now i get another error :/

Comment: @Pajkec As I said, your current solution cannot work like that.

Comment: Can you please explain why? I mean what is the difference if i run the code directly or with execute statement (the string statement is exactly the same as written code).

Comment: @Pajkec To rephrase my answer, because execute statement does not work that way: it only supports DSQL, not PSQL statement. It uses the same API that you use to execute queries from an application or query tool, that doesn't support PSQL either.

Comment: I still don't understand it but OK... So what can i do? i really dont want to write it in the long notation with all those IF sentences and when i will add a column i would need to change it every time...

Comment: @Pajkec The only way besides writing the trigger code yourself would be to use a code-generator to generate the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my example based on Mark's example above and working in Firebird 3.0:

```
SET TERM ^ ;
CREATE TRIGGER UMCDB_DRIVER_BI FOR UMCDB_DRIVER ACTIVE
BEFORE INSERT POSITION 0
AS 
BEGIN 
    new.ID = gen_id(GEN_DRIVER, 1);
    new.CREATE_USERID = CURRENT_USER;
    new.CREATE_TS = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
    -- Get the hashed value for the driver name.
    execute procedure PRC_NAME_HASH( new.DRVR_FIRST_NAME, new.DRVR_MID_INITS, new.DRVR_LAST_NAME)
        returning_values new.NAME_HASH;
END^
SET TERM ; ^
```

Works beautifully!  Thanks, Mark!